# Adding additional form depending on the choice of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm stacked.
here is code

```
<div class="form-group">

           <%= f.radio_button :repeat, 'once', checked: true%><br>
           <%= f.label :repeat_once, 'once'%><br>
           <%= f.radio_button :repeat, 'daily'%><br>
           <%=f.label :repeat_daily, 'daily'%><br>
           <%= f.radio_button :repeat, 'weekly'%><br>
           <%= f.label :repeat_weekly, 'weekly'%><br>
           <%= f.radio_button :repeat, 'monthly'%><br>
           <%= f.label :repeat_monthly, 'monthly'%><br>
           <%= f.radio_button :repeat, 'yearly'%><br>
           <%=f.label :repeat_yearly, 'yearly' %><br>
         </div>
  `<% if @event.repeat == 'daily' %>
           <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :Repeating_interval_in_days %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :interval %>
      </div>
       <% end %>
        <% if @event.repeat == 'weekly' %>
           <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :Repeating_interval_in_weeks %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :interval %>
      </div>
       <% end %>
       <% if @event.repeat == 'monthly' %>
           <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :Repeating_interval_in_month %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :interval %>
      </div>
       <% end %>
       <% if @event.repeat == 'yearly' %>
           <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :Repeating_interval_in_years %><br>
        <%= f.number_field :interval %>
      </div>
       <% end %>
```

I want to extra field of choosing interval of repeating  when User set a type of repeat. My code doesn't work.

Comment: What are you trying to do?. do you want to edit a persisted object? or create a new one with this form?

Comment: Its creating new object.

Comment: Then, I think your `if` conditional portion should be handled on client side through javascript. Because there is no chance for user to check the radio button as the entire form is already rendered by your app.

Comment: Ruby on Rails doesn't do client side listening unless you want to have a new page load every time a button is clicked. As was suggested you're going to have to use some type of client side programming language like javascript to listen for the button presses/dropdowns/whatever.

Comment: Just to add to @MCBama's answer, you're going to probably want to use something like jQuery to listen for a click/action/etc. on a specific field in your form in order to render another partial into the DOM.